# What is the difference between user profile and bash profile on a unix server

Tags: linux, bash

My unix environment does not have a user profile file, it only has a bash profile? What are the differences between the two?

If I add an environment variable to bash profile as opposed to user profile, what effect does this have?

Comment: ...however -- how this is a programming question as opposed to a user-environment-configuration question escapes me. Perhaps http://superuser.com/ would be the better place?

Comment: ...btw, this topic is all covered in `man bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If your login shell is bash, and a `~/.bash_profile` exists

Creation or editing of a `~/.profile` would have no effect, as your login shell (bash) will use only `~/.bash_profile` if that file exists. (An exception may exist if your `~/.bash_profile` explicitly sources contents of any extant `~/.profile`)

By contrast, editing your `~/.bash_profile` will (as you expect) allow you to modify the state of a new login session.

---

#### If your login shell is bash, and no `~/.bash_profile` exists

If a `~/.profile` exists, or is created, and no `~/.bash_profile` exists, it will be sourced by bash on login.

---

#### If you change your login shell to a non-bash shell

`~/.bash_profile` will be ignored (typically), and only `~/.profile` (if it exists) used.